# Initialize topmost UWP window from the constructor

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Weird issue.
I'm trying to build a desktop app that has an option to open a second "window".
So Foo opens Bar.
Only Bar should, by default, be a topmost window.
The below method works just fine, when called by a button click.

```
    private async Task<bool> MakeTopMost()
    {
        await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
    }
```

However, when called from the page constructor, via an Action,

```
 new Action(async () => await MakeTopMost())();
```

...
Lo and behold. Nothing happens. I've tried the Loaded event also. No dice.
What am I missing?

Edit:
A workaround would be the button clicked to open a new app also makes the app topmost. Like so:

```
    private async void ShowCompactView()
    {
        var compactViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            var frame = new Frame();

            frame.Navigate(typeof(BAR));
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "CompactOverlay Window";
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(compactViewId, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
    }
```

But that makes the whole app topmost (not just a page).

Answer (score 0):

What I basically did in the method posted last in the question was

1. Get the id of the application page currently displayed
2. Open a new page.
3. Compact overlay the id. Which was the main page. So basically the entire app was set as topmost.

So, by using a variable to hold the id of the newly opened page, the BAR, we can open a page from FOO that's automatically set as topmost.

private int _barID;

```
    private async void ShowCompactView()
    {
        await CoreApplication.CreateNewView().Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            var frame = new Frame();

            frame.Navigate(typeof(Bar));
            _barID = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            Window.Current.Activate();
            ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Title = "CompactOverlay Window";
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsViewModeAsync(sliderID, ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
    }
```

it should have been obvious.